# Comparing strings from two files within two while loops in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to locate the strings present in both txt files (one from argv[2], one from stdin), but my loop is only testing the first line of string from the first file with the rest of the second file. I can't seem to figure out why my program doesnt move back into "locations to check against" for each ticket despite having the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN (15)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char buf[15];
char buflocation[6];
char location[6];

FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2],"r");


while (fgets(buf, BUFLEN, stdin) != NULL) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<4; i++){
        location[i] = buf[i];

    }

    printf("location of ticket we are testing is %s\n",location);

    while (fgets(buflocation,sizeof(buflocation),fp) != NULL){


            printf("location to check against:%s",buflocation);
                if (strncmp(location,buflocation,4) == 0){
                        printf("this ticket is valid %s\n",buf);
                    }
    }
}



fclose(fp);
return 0;

}
```

and this is the *output*

```
location of ticket we are testing is 1111
location to check against:0101
location to check against:0027
location to check against:1009
location to check against:0077
location to check against:1111
this ticket is valid 111122222220
location of ticket we are testing is 1111
location of ticket we are testing is 9876
location of ticket we are testing is 4526
location of ticket we are testing is 7368
```

so if my next ticket was 100967789654 then it should come out as valid as well because 1009 is a valid location, but it just doesnt read into that second line. am i not declaring my while statements correctly?

Comment: So, fgets will continue reading from where it left off in the fp file.  You need to "start over" by using fseek to the begining of the file  http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html

Comment: after reading that link isn't it sufficient to use rewind(fp) at the end of the inner while loop? output is what im after but is it doing something in the background that i cant see?

Comment: I've never used rewind before.  user58697's answer below is the code I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner while loop keeps reads the file to the end. At the second iteration of the outer loop the file is already positioned at the end of file. To force rereading, you need to reposition file back to the beginning with:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 1):

when filling your char array you need to terminate it with `'\0'` character

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   char location[10];

   location[0]='a';
   location[1]='b';
   location[2]='c';
   location[3]='\0'; // not adding this is undefined behavior

   printf("%s", location);
}
```

Comment: You're right that the string copied into `location` is not null terminated and that should be fixed.  I'm not quite so sure that "won't display your string" is accurate.  It will most likely display the string and may well add some extra characters to the output.  The behaviour is undefined, and that's always bad.  So +1 for observing that the string is nor guaranteed to be null terminated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right , sorry for writing "won't display" i will edit.